# for loops in C with incrementing a counter and short-hand counter++

Tags: c

```
for i := 0 to 5 do 
begin 
i := i + 1;
    counter++ 
end;
```

I am trying to write the code for a loop in C that will increment a  counter from 0 to 5, writing out the counter value with each iteration. Use the C  short-hand: counter++ to increment counter by 1 in each iteration of the loop. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Er, no. (1) That looks more like Pascal than C; (2) There's no need to increment `i` by hand, the loop will do that; (3) There's no need to keep a second counter that presumably has the same value as `i`; (4) Where's the printing? (5) Why not pose that question to the compiler instead of wasting our time?

Comment: Read a C book please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a correct syntax in C.

You must write it like :

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++ )
{
    printf("Value of i: %d\n", i);
}
```

For more information: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm